# Measuring execution time across a pipeline of multiple Java applications

Tags: java, performance, runtime, timing

I have a set of applications that form a pipeline of a workflow. An event is triggered at the **ingress** *(a Java application)* and some processing happens and the flow is transferred to the next application in the pipeline. The flow continues like this until the last application at the end - the **egress** *(also a Java application)*.

I want to calculate the total time taken from the event-trigger until the last task in the **egress** application.

So far I have used **System.currentTimeMillis()** and **System.nanoTime()** to log the time when the event is triggered and then again to log-time upon the last *egress* application completes its task. And then I take the difference between these two to measure the total time taken for the whole event.

Now when I compare the results I get *(for the times measured as stated above)* against just a manual clock time validation, I see that it is almost very accurate. However, I am not very sure whether it is the correct way to do it since they (ingress and egress) are independent processes. I see that since **currentTimeMillis** has a fixed reference and since both processes run in the same host with the same system time, it will not be an issue.

But I read that **nanoTime** is an arbitrary reference from the JVM. If so will it be the same for two independent java apps running separate JVM instances? How come the calculation using **nanoTime()** across separate processes also gives a precise time-interval.

Besides what is the most appropriate way to calculate runtime for such one-way pipelines of many applications? Is the approach I have taken correct?

**PS:** I have used both the above APIs since I read that **nanoTime** is more precise and wanted to just compare them.

Answer (score 1):

You should be ok with what you are doing because the hardware instructions used to get the time should be consistent regardless of the CPU that you are running on. Since Java needs to contend with nanoTime() being called on 2 potentially different CPUs (if the application itself is multi-threaded) and being able to compare those times, it should already be ensuring that it is using a hardware-wide timer and not a thread or CPU-specific timer. 
Now - if you were running different java processes on different hardware systems, that would be a different matter...